# Which costumes affect artes and titles?

Tags: tales-of-arise

I've read that some of the DLC costumes affect the artes and titles in the game, but can't find any other related information on this.

Which DLC costumes give additional artes or change artes?

Which DLC costumes give additional titles? What do the titles do and what skills can I gain with the DLC?

Comment: I bought the Samurai DLC set for male and female, and each hero got a new Skill Title to work on. They are mostly about 1000 to 1500 SP, and the skills vary between each character. Screenshotted the ones I have https://imgur.com/a/Kqn0KC0